# JavaScript absolute position of element on images

Tags: javascript

I have created a new div and adding it to all images on the page as follows:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {    
var divLink = document.createElement("div");
    divLink.style.position = "absolute"; divLink.style.top = "10px"; divLink.style.right = "10px"; divLink.style.zIndex="1"; divLink.style.fontSize = "20px"; divLink.style.backgroundColor = "black"; divLink.style.color = 'white';
    divLink.innerHTML = linkCount;
    images[i].parentNode.insertBefore(divLink, images[i] );
}
```

This is working well for all images except images contained in a `<ul>`. For these images, each divLink is moved to the right of the `<ul>` and stacked on top of one another. If I remove the `divLink.style.right = "10px";` the divLink moves by default to the left of the image.

How can I position the divLink to the top-right corner of the image, for all images including those in the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `relative` position instead of `absolute`

```
divLink.style.position = "relative";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add poistion:absolute and mention top/left/right/bottom , the elements tends to stack on each other .

There are 2 ways to do this :

1> Do not assign any position.Let it remain "STATIC". Move the "images" using the margin properties.

Eg:

```
 divLink.style.margin-top = "10px";
 divLink.style.margin-right= "10px";
        OR
```

2> Make just the position:absolute without mentioning top/left/right/bottom properties, this way they will not stack on each other. Unless you don't want to move the "images" explicitly using top/left, that is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

There seems no need to give position:absolute to the images.
You can simply append the images without giving the position attribute and move the images using the margin property.

```
  divLink.style.margin-top = "10px";
  divLink.style.margin-right= "10px";
```